# When using pyenv to manage python versions, how do I install dependancies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependencies, pyenv

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. On a default install there is no python version.

I've installed pyenv in order to use specific python-based programs.

Some of the programs I want to install have dependencies that are usually installed using pip. However, because there is no system python on-board, there is no pip.

Now, I could go and install system python, in which case I'd have access to pip... and also install python3 in order to use install python3 deps. But this seems like overkill to me. And for all I know, I might be creating complications that hit me further down the road.

So how do I do dependency management when using managed python versions?

Comment: sudo apt install python3 python3-pip python3-venv

Comment: That's the answer to the question "how do I install python, python3 and pip for both", but it doesn't really answer my question about whether this is the only or best approach.